# Split and concatenate name for four textfield using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have four rows. Each row has first name and lastname. I need to concatenate first name and lastname. After concatenating it should appear in the label.

```
<input type='text'  id='fnamer1'  style='width:185px;height:20px;text-align:right;font-size:11px;background:white' onblur='Change(this, event);concatName()' onfocus='Change(this, event)'></td>";

<input type='text' id='lnamer1' style='width:185px;height:20px;text-align:right;font-size:11px;background:white' onblur='Change(this, event);concatName()' onfocus='Change(this, event)'></td>";

function concatName()
{  
        document.getElementById('disName').innerHTML="";
        var fname = document.getElementById("fnamer0").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lnamer0").value;
        var splitfname = fname.substring(0,1);
        var splitlname = lname.substring(0,4);
        var joinStr = splitlname+splitfname;
        document.getElementById('disName').innerHTML=joinStr.toUpperCase();
}
```

This is for 1st row but how can I do this for four rows?

Comment: If this works for one row, why not use the same logic?  Maybe add a loop?

Comment: what do you mean by 4 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an index variable to tell concatName which item you want to work with:

```
function concatName(index)
{  
        document.getElementById('disName').innerHTML="";
        // this might be: document.getElementById('disName' + index).innerHTML="";
        var fname = document.getElementById("fnamer" + index).value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lnamer" + index).value;
        var splitfname = fname.substring(0,1);
        var splitlname = lname.substring(0,4);
        var joinStr = splitlname+splitfname;
        document.getElementById('disName').innerHTML=joinStr.toUpperCase();
        // this might be: document.getElementById('disName' + index).innerHTML=joinStr.toUpperCase();
}
```

Then:

```
concatName(0);
concatName(1);
concatName(2);
concatName(3);
```

Or:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 concatName(i); 
}
```